# Не выходит преобразование (явное и неявное) из string в int

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Как не пытался крутить преоразования как явные так и неявные не получается преобразовать из string в int. Пробовал и Convert и int.Parse но ничего не помогло.

```
public void ConnServer()
    {

        try
        {
            Form1 form1 = new Form1();
            int _port = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            string _ip = textBox1.Text;
            IPAddress Adip = IPAddress.Parse(_ip);
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(Adip, _port);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
            socket.SendTimeout = 5000;
            socket.Connect(iPEndPoint);
            if (socket.Connected == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Подключен к серверу!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Подключение не удалось!");
            }
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
            byte[] info = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_clientConnect.Fam.ToString());
            socket.Send(info);
            info = new byte[512];
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            int bytes = 0;
            do
            {
                bytes = socket.Receive(info, info.Length, 0);
                stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(info, 0, bytes));
            }
            while (socket.Available > 0);
            MessageBox.Show("Ответ:" + stringBuilder.ToString());
            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Close();
            //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка №" + ex);
        }

    }
```

Выбивает ошибку в int _port = int32.Parse(textBox2.text);
По гуглу видел что много людей сталкивались с такой ошибкой но их решения проблем мне не помогли.[image: Ошибка которую выбивает]

Comment: А какое значение лежит в textBox1.Text?

Comment: Если у Вас проблема с одной строкой кода, то оставьте только ее.

Answer (score 2):

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx
```

> int.TryParse

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      String[] values = { null, "160519", "9432.0", "16,667",
                          "   -322   ", "+4302", "(100);", "01FA" };
      foreach (var value in values) {
         int number;

         bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
         if (result)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
         }
         else
         {
//            if (value == null) value = ""; 
            Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", 
                               value == null ? "<null>" : value);
         }
      }
   }
}

 // Выводится следующий результат:
// Попытка преобразования '<null>' не удалась.
// Превратить 160519 на 160519.
// Попытка преобразования '9432.0' не удалась.
// Попытка преобразования '16 667' не удалась.
// Превратить -322 до -322.
// Преобразовано '+4302 ' в 4302.
// Попытка преобразования '(100); ' не удалась.
// Попытка преобразования '01FA' не удалась.
```

PS if (socket.Connected == true) ~~ if (socket.Connected)